# My raspberry Pi Won't let me log in as a superuser

Tags: linux, bash

Here's the code I'm Using:
'''pi@raspberrypi:~ $ su
'''
And here's what I'm getting:
'''Password:
su: Authentication failure
'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

su implies that you know the root password:
Try **sudo -i** instead.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing code_. Questions about using UNIX tools (when not used in a manner specifically relevant to scripting or other development-centric tasks) are off-topic and should be closed, not answered -- see the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked!